# How to get currency name by country code?

Tags: java, android, currency, country-codes

I want to get the currency name by country code. I get the country code with the following code:

```
    TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String countrycode=manager.getNetworkCountryIso();
    System.out.println("---->"+countrycode+"<----");
```

Now I want to get currency by using this country code. How can i do this?

Comment: How many countries are you going for?   Maybe you could have a if- or switch solution yourself?

Comment: Have you got an array of currency codes for each country? I am a php developer I dont know why this question got tagged in PHP.

Comment: No I got only one code for a single device based on the network.It may be get by web services that time we have to use php thats why I tagged PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the currency by using this util and load from country code.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Currency.html

Answer (score -1):

I've used the [Currency](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/util/Currency.html) class and the default [Locale](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/util/Locale.html) to get the current currency code (ISO 4217) with the following code:

```
Currency.getInstance(Locale.getDefault()).getCurrencyCode()
```

You can also replace the Locale with your custom Country Code ;)

Comment: How to replace locale with country code safely?